# MySQL query with multiple AND statement

Tags: mysql, relational-division

I have database table like this:

```
|id |item    |
|1  |item-1  |
|2  |item-1  |
|1  |item-2  |
|3  |item-3  |
|2  |item-2  |
|1  |item-3  |
```

How in MySQL get id who hes item-1 AND item-2?

This don't work:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE item = 'item-1' AND item = 'item-2'
```

I know why it doesn't work, but how to get a result like this:

```
|id |
|1  |
|2  |
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think the intention is to get `id` values which have both items, not either item.

Comment: WHERE item IN ('item-1', 'item-2') - That I use now but that is not what I need. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin that is same problem.

Comment: You can also click the [tag:relational-division] tag to see other solutions.

Comment: @BillKarwin Opps you are probably right

Answer (score 0):

for every additional condition you can use EXISTS

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE item = 'item-1' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table  WHERE item = 'item-2')
```